# Quartz Jobs Not Kicking Off

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

**Edit**: I am using `quartz-2.1.5.jar`. Here's the summary of my classes:

> `HttpPollingJob` extends `PollingJob` extends `ScheduledJob` implements `org.quartz.Job`

Specifically:

1) `ScheduledJob` implements Quartz `Job` (abstract base class for all my `Job` types):

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.Trigger;

public abstract class ScheduledJob implements Job {
    private Trigger trigger;

    public ScheduledJob() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ScheduledJob(Trigger trig) {
        super();

        if(trig == null)
            trig = getDefaultTrigger();

        setTrigger(trig);
    }

    public Trigger getTrigger() {
        return trigger;
    }

    public void setTrigger(final Trigger trig) {
        trigger = trig;
    }

    protected abstract Trigger getDefaultTrigger();
}
```

2) `PollingJob` extends `ScheduledJob` - all "pollers" poll some resource/endpoint with a specific frequency:

```
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;

import com.me.jobs.ScheduledJob;

public abstract class PollingJob extends ScheduledJob {
    private static long DEF_FREQUENCY = 10 * 1000; // 10 secs
    private String name;    
    private long frequency;

    public PollingJob(final String nm) {
        this(nm, DEF_FREQUENCY);
    }

    public PollingJob(final String nm, final long freq) {
        super();

        setName(nm);
        setFrequency(freq);
    }

    public abstract void poll(JobExecutionContext context);

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        poll(context);      
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String nm) {
        name = nm;
    }

    public long getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(final long freq) {
        frequency = freq;
    }

    protected final Trigger getDefaultTrigger()  {
        TriggerBuilder<?> triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInMilliseconds(DEF_FREQUENCY));

        return triggerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

3) `HttpPollingJob` extends `PollingJob` - "HTTP pollers" poll a web server (using HTtpClient):

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;

import com.me.MonitoredEvent;
import com.me.MonitoredEventRegistrar;

public class HttpPollingJob extends PollingJob {
    private String serverURL;
    private org.slf4j.Logger logger =
        org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpPollingJob.class);

    public HttpPollingJob(final String nm, final String server) {
        super(nm);

        setServerURL(server);
    }

    public String getServerURL() {
        return serverURL;
    }

    public void setServerURL(final String server) {
        serverURL = server;
    }

    @Override
    public final void poll(JobExecutionContext context) {
        MonitoredEvent event = null;

        try {
            // This is where we would use HttpClient to connect to a web server and poll it.
            System.out.println("Job fired!");
        }
        catch(Throwable thrown) {
            logger.error(thrown.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

4) `JobDriver` - defines several `HttpPollingJob`s and uses Quartz to start them:

```
public class JobDriver {
    private List<HttpPollingJob> jobs;

    public JobDriver() {
        HttpPollingJob job1 = new HttpPollingJob("job-1", "http://www.example.com/1");
        HttpPollingJob job2 = new HttpPollingJob("job-2", "http://www.example.com/2");
        HttpPollingJob job3 = new HttpPollingJob("job-3", "http://www.example.com/3");

        jobs = new ArrayList<HttpPollingJob>();
        jobs.add(job1);
        jobs.add(job2);
        jobs.add(job3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobDriver driver = new JobDriver();
        driver.startJobs();
    }

    private void startJobs() {
        try {
            // Obtain a basic SchedulerFactory and fire it up.
            SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();

            // Define a job for every declared monitor.
            JobBuilder jobBuilder = null;

            for(ScheduledJob job : jobs) {

            Trigger trigger = job.getTrigger();
            jobBuilder = JobBuilder.newJob(job.getClass());

            // Bind the current job to this trigger.
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobBuilder.build(), trigger);

            // TODO: Shut the scheduler down politely?!?!
        }
        catch(Throwable exc) {
            logger.error(exc.getMessage());

            // Force application to kick out.
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get a perfect startup with no errors or runtime exceptions. If I sprinkle `System.out.println` statements I can see every single line of code executing flawlessly. The only problem is, once the program is running, its not printing the "*Job fired!*" message indicating that the polling job is kicking off.

I've tried every combination of `start()` and `shutdown()` I can think of to no avail. Can any Quartz mavens look at this code and tell me why the job isn't firing?

In the logs (I configured log4j) I see the Quartz worker thread being created for the scheduled job.  I feel like I'm 99% of the way there but am just missing something obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thats not fair, I gave the correct answer first. how can you award bounty to an answer that is given after bounty is closed. unethical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its your constructors - the `JobBuilder` looks for the no-args and since they're not defined it refuses to build the jobs. Add empty no-arg ctors and you're all set.

Comment: wow, you gave a bounty to yourself, can we report this answer?

Answer (score 16):

@4herpsand7derpsago yes you are right, you are 99% there, I ran your code and there is only one problem in it, the Default constructors are absent in `HttpPollingJob` and `PollingJob` classes, For that reason Scheduler is not able to create their instances,

Simple Solution add following code in below classes
**HttpPollingJob** class

```
public HttpPollingJob() {
}
```

**PollingJob** class

```
public PollingJob() {
}
```

Bingo, the following messages will be printed

`Job fired!`
`Job fired!`
`Job fired!`

If you want to repeat the trigger, add following code in **PollingJob**

```
protected final Trigger getDefaultTrigger() {
    TriggerBuilder<?> triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                            .withIntervalInMilliseconds(DEF_FREQUENCY).repeatForever());

    return triggerBuilder.build();
}
```

Hoping that now I will receive the bounty :)

**BONUS**
Seems like you want to poll or do something with urls, A better way to pass that using king `JobDataMap`

Updated **JobDriver**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.Trigger;

public class JobDriver {
private List<HttpPollingJob> jobs;

public JobDriver() {
    HttpPollingJob job1 = new HttpPollingJob("job-1",
            "http://www.example.com/1");
    HttpPollingJob job2 = new HttpPollingJob("job-2",
            "http://www.example.com/2");
    HttpPollingJob job3 = new HttpPollingJob("job-3",
            "http://www.example.com/3");

    jobs = new ArrayList<HttpPollingJob>();
    jobs.add(job1);
    jobs.add(job2);
    jobs.add(job3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobDriver driver = new JobDriver();
    driver.startJobs();
}

private void startJobs() {
    try {
        // Obtain a basic SchedulerFactory and fire it up.
        SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        // Define a job for every declared monitor.
        JobBuilder jobBuilder = null;

        for (HttpPollingJob job : jobs) {

            Trigger trigger = job.getTrigger();
            jobBuilder = JobBuilder.newJob(job.getClass());
            jobBuilder.usingJobData("name", job.getName());
            jobBuilder.usingJobData("url", job.getServerURL());

            // Bind the current job to this trigger.
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobBuilder.build(), trigger);

            // TODO: Shut the scheduler down politely?!?!
        }


    } catch (Throwable exc) {
        // Force application to kick out.
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
}
}
```

updated **HttpPollingJob**

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;

public class HttpPollingJob extends PollingJob {
private String serverURL;
private org.slf4j.Logger logger =
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpPollingJob.class);

public HttpPollingJob(final String nm, final String server) {
    super(nm);

    setServerURL(server);
}
public HttpPollingJob() {
}

public String getServerURL() {
    return serverURL;
}

public void setServerURL(final String server) {
    serverURL = server;
}

@Override
public final void poll(JobExecutionContext context) {

    try {
        Map dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        String nm = (String)dataMap.get("name");
        String url = (String)dataMap.get("url");
        // This is where we would use HttpClient to connect to a web server and poll it.
        System.out.println("Job fired! name:"+nm+" url:"+url);
    }
    catch(Throwable thrown) {
        logger.error(thrown.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

**new output**

`Job fired! name:job-1 url:http://www.example.com/1`
`Job fired! name:job-2 url:http://www.example.com/2`
`Job fired! name:job-3 url:http://www.example.com/3`

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago did you check my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, you have not started the trigger. See [Quartz Tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02) or [Javadocs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html):

```
// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
  Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
      .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
      .startNow()
      .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
          .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
          .repeatForever())            
      .build();
```

Comment: This is still not working... Any other ideas? +1 for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change the code of the method `getDefaultTrigger` in the class `PollingJob` into the following :

```
    protected final Trigger getDefaultTrigger()  {

return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
         .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInMilliseconds(DEF_FREQUENCY))
        .startAt(DateBuilder.futureDate(1,  DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.SECOND))
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i feel some issue with the way you create the trigger. 
Remember you cannot reuse trigger for multiple jobs

Try creating trigger with unique identity and group like below

Trigger everyHourTrigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("everyWeeklyTrigger", "group1")
            .startNow().withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 1 * * * ?")).build();